# Riemann-Stieltjes integral exercises

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Recently I was looking for some source for exercises in Riemann-Stieltjes integral and going through several calculus books (Hunt, Edwards, Thomas, Adams) I found no such exercises. Is there any exercise\problem book which covers Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: They come up naturally in some parts of Analytic Number Theory, so you might look for a textbook on that subject, Apostol or Shapiro or some other.

Answer (score 5):

Chapter 7 of T.M. Apostol's "[Mathematical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201002884)" has a good deal both of theory and exercises about the R.S. integral.

Also R.G. Bartle's "[The Elements of Real Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047105464X)", section 22, chapter VI, has many examples and exercises.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 2 of Zygmund and Wheeden's "[Measure and Integral](http://books.google.com/books/about/Measure_and_Integral.html?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC)" has some exercises regarding the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://books.google.com/books/about/Advanced_calculus.html?id=3TjvAAAAMAAJ) book begins the study of the integral from the general Riemann-Stieltjes Integral. The topic is covered adequately as would be expected from an undergraduate introductory text on real analysis. There are a good number of exercises at the end of the chapter.

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I use this book

Leonard F. Richardson: Advanced calculus, an introduction to linear analysis. Wiley-Interscience (2008).

In chapter 7, you will find detailed proofs and exercises.